# Howto Create a right-click "move up" command

Tags: windows, registry

I want to make a command in Windows right-click context menu which moves a file up one directory (to it's parent directory).

I added a new key to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`

```
Key: "Move Up"
    Key: "command" Data: cmd /c move "%1%" "..\%1" /Y
```

but it doesn't work.  I see a shell pop open, and close instantly, and the file doesn't move.

What am I missing?

Comment: The 'move' command isn't an intrinsic in cmd. Is it an external utility? Is it on the path?

Comment: Why is this tagged regex?